# Passing parent class by reference to nested class, how does it affect performance?

Tags: php

I am using the following code:

```
class parent {
    protected $oChild;

    function __construct() {
        $this->oChild = new child();
        $this->oChild->setParentPointer($this);
    }
}

class child {
    protected $oParent;

    public function setParentPointer(&$oParent) {
        $this->oParent = $oParent;
    }

    private function getParent() {
        return $this->oParent;
    }
}
```

### Questions:

- How does PHP manages this reference, does it create a pointer or
  duplicate the class data?
- Does it store all the data and functions of the parent into the child
  and thus duplicating the used memory?
- Is there a better way to call the parent class in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP [objects are passed by reference by default](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php). So no data is duplicated and there is no impact on performance. Also, there is no need to use the `&` symbol.

It is hard to tell if there is a better way to do this because it is a software design question and it depends on the context. Generally, it is recommended to avoid circular references but it doesn't mean you can't do that when needed.